# Review audit failed for first answer, the reason is the question is duplicate

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

A review audit failed. It's a first answer.

[image: banned]

The review was:

[image: Review history]

From the comment, I can see:

> Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one
>   good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as
>   duplicates.

My question is that while reviewing the answer, whether we have to check whether the question is duplicate or not?

Here, If the question is not duplicate, I think the answer is "actually an answer".

Let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were a couple things to clue you in to the fact that this was a bad answer and possibly an audit.

the comment:

> Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, tailor your answers to the question.

This is telling you that the user has been posting this exact answer on multiple questions which is something we should not be doing.  If a question can be answered with the exact same answer then the question should be duplicates.

The second piece of information is who wrote the comment.  [Martijn Pieters♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) is a moderator, when you see a moderator commenting on behavior that normally means they got involved.  In this case he deleted the answer.

If you had opened the question up in your browser to check it out more you would have seen that this answer does not exist unless you have 10K reputation as the answer is deleted.  Opening a question to check on it is not considered cheating as it demonstrates that you are paying attention.

> My question is that while reviewing the answer, whether we have to check whether the question is duplicate or not?

No we do not have to check if the question is a duplicate but seeing the comment and who it was from and the quality of the answer means the answer warranted some additional checking.  As I said if you had gone to the question you would not have even seen the answer which tells you it was deleted.

Comment: accepting the answer... but I don't think I can open each question that I'm going to review... 
 :)

Comment: "If a question can be answered with the exact same answer then the question should be duplicates." Mathematics would like a word...